# Почему пропал перевод тревог в окне тревог?

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, тревоги

Почему-то в окне тревог исчез перевод (скрин прилагаю). Но интересно, что перевод исчез только частично (только у кратких описаний тревог, описание более развёрнутых на месте)

[image: нет перевода]

Надо бы это исправить...

Comment: заменили строки в транзификсе - перевод и слетел

Comment: @Grundy можете повесить на вопрос метку статус-завершено? Проблема-то исправлена(см. ответ).

Comment: Обычно метка вешается когда точно завершено, то есть уже применилось.

Comment: @Grundy так применилось уже.

Comment: @Grundy перевод [уже есть](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNnrg.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Оригинальные строки стали писаться с прописной буквы и прежние переводы поэтому отвалились. Пример:

> [image: Very low quality]

Некоторые строки с заглавными буквами уже использовались в других местах и были переведены. Поэтому для них перевод визуально не слетел. Хотя фактически он стал другим.

Обновил переводы. Будет доступно в новых сборках. Текущая rev 2023.3.7.43282

Comment: "будет доступно в новых сборках" - немного не понял, можете пожалуйста объяснить, что это значит?

Comment: @Зонтик значит что надо немного подождать

Comment: @Зонтик см `rev 2023.3.8.XXXXX` внизу страницы. Эта текущий билд. Несколько раз в рабочий день сайт обновляется. Для того, чтобы переводы подхватились, нужен инкремент сборки.